# Will questions about iptables, or other host-based firewall software, be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I suspect we are going to see a lot of questions about iptables, (and other flavors of on-host firewall/packet filtering.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see how that might depend on the question, but in general I think that is going to be more of a serverfault or possibly security question.

Answer (score 10):

In my mind, that would depend on the context.

If it is iptables running on a Linux box being used as a router or firewall on the network?  Yes, it is on topic.

If it is iptables running on a Linux box and users can't access my website?  No, it is better servered at SF or Unix & Linux.

Comment: Absolutely, most firewalls are not much else than stock linux with COTS HW where flows are moved after inspection. No point discriminating.

Comment: [sf] is a fine place for these questions, and they are well-loved there.  iptables firewalls are not a real commercial-grade solution, and that should be the focus of this site

Answer (score 3):

I.e. if someone would ask about VRFs on Linux or network namespaces that would be most on-topic i think.

Traffic shaping could be a good gray area to think about.

Plain iptables firewalling probably doesn't really ring "network engineering" and would not really contribute anything.

Comment: +1 Standard iptables questions belong on ServerFault or Linux and Unix Users. Advanced networking topics like VRFs, or enablnig MPLS on a Linux server NIC, and bringing up an LDP/RSVP neighbour-ship would be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

At the *concept* level, yes.  But in the specifics, not so much as it's an OS level question at that point -- and depends on a number of OS-side specifics.

Comment: I would disagree with this, on these grounds we would have to deal only with the concept level and not the OS level specifics of IOS, Nexus, ASA, JunOS, and so on.  Ultimately, the OS may not be what some are familiar with, but that doesn't make it any less valid as a network device when used in that context.